# How can I reach this platform?

Tags: portal-2

I am in the 1970s facility right now right after you hear Cave Johnson talking about combustible lemons :P at the start of a chamber that looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

So I started exploring and found out that I need to make it to this platform:
[image: screenshot]

...to be able to make use of the steady stream of repulsion gel up there.  Only problem is I can't seem to find a single way to get up there.  I have tried again and again and again so if anyone knows how to do this please let me know!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think the feeling of succes will be greater when you've solved it yourself. But that's just me. If you really want to know, watch this video:

Comment: This answer will lose its usefulness if the video ever disappears. To fix that, consider summarising the relevant steps in text, behind a spoiler tag if you like. (Spoiler tags are created by starting a line with `>! `.)